# High voltage +170V based on NE555 design - short circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, pcb-design, high-voltage, 555, nixie

I love Nixie tubes so I decided to build a Nixie clock.

I am a beginner. I have one successful design that electronics SE helped me design.

That PCB was based on through-hole components and an Arduino.

Now I decided to try a SMD design (and I think way more complicated than the previous one.)

This design is based on an `NE555` as that is the simplest one I could find online. This PCB is just to test the power supply generation and the drive of one Nixie tube `IN-14`. It is not the final circuit.

Here is the design:

Input voltage +12V

[image: Input voltage +12V]

+170V generation

[image: +170V generation]

PCB without ground plane

[image: PCB without ground plane]

PCB with ground plane

[image: PCB with ground plane]

Picture of PCBA

[image]

What I know / found out:

- I miscalculated the +9V `LM317` resistors, it should be 1620 ohm and I soldered 1500 ohm.
- Footprint of the fuse is way off, I soldered a wire to short it
- C12 should be 100uF as per datasheet recommanded circuit
- C14 is a 4.7u 400V aluminium capacitor (should have been 470uF.)

What is happening:

My power supply is showing a short circuit. I wire `+9V@1A` (current limited) on the +9V test points as the +9V generation doesn't work.

Using a very scientific method (my fingers) I feel that `Q26 (IRF740)` is getting very hot.

Checking with my multimeter shows no short on any of the components (continuity mode) +9V and ground are not shorted when the power is off.

Is the +9V generation a must or can I feed the +12V to the NE555 circuit?

Can you guys see a problem in the design, maybe the choice of the components?

Farnell codes :

- RV2 : [2786536](https://fr.farnell.com/littelfuse/v240ch8t/varistance-mov-395v-3220/dp/2786536?ost=2786536)
- D1, D8, D10 ES3J : [2677398](https://fr.farnell.com/taiwan-semiconductor/es3j-r6g/diode-simple-3a-600v-do-214ab/dp/2677398?ost=2677398)
- F1 : [3701350](https://fr.farnell.com/aem/t0603ff1250tm/fusible-tres-rapide-1-25a-65vdc/dp/3701350?ost=3701350)
- C3, C5, C11, C12 : [3013452](https://fr.farnell.com/samsung-electro-mechanics/cl21a106kaynnne/condensateur-10uf-25v-mlcc-0805/dp/3013452?ost=3013452)
- C14 4.7u 400V RS code [725-6966](https://fr.rs-online.com/web/p/condensateurs-electrolytiques/7256966) (not 470u)
- C10 : [2812527](https://fr.farnell.com/wurth-elektronik/885342007006/cond-47pf-500v-5-c0g-np0-0805/dp/2812527?ost=2812527)
- C9 : [3489975](https://fr.farnell.com/tdk/c5750x7r2e105m230ke/condensateur-1uf-250v-mlcc-2220/dp/3489975?ost=3489975)
- L1 : [3370508](https://fr.farnell.com/multicomp-pro/mp002851/inductance-de-puiss-100uh-blind/dp/3370508?ost=3370508)
- Q26 : [8657815](https://fr.farnell.com/vishay/irf740aspbf/transistor-mosfet-canal-n-d2pak/dp/8657815?ost=8657815)
- Q25 : [2706710](https://fr.farnell.com/rohm/sst2907ahzgt116/transistor-pnp-60v-0-6a-sot-23/dp/2706710?ost=2706710)
- Q24 : [1081232](https://fr.farnell.com/nexperia/bc847b-215/transistor-npn-sot-23/dp/1081232?ost=1081232)
- U12 NE555DR : [3121192](https://fr.farnell.com/texas-instruments/ne555dr/timer-single-precision-soic8-555/dp/3121192?ost=3121192)
- U2 : [2383003](https://fr.farnell.com/texas-instruments/lm1117sx-5-0-nopb/800ma-low-dropout-linear-regulator/dp/2383003?ost=2383003%20*)
- D9 : [1081180](https://fr.farnell.com/nexperia/bas16-215/diode-de-commutation-100v-215ma/dp/1081180?st=1081180)

[EDIT]
Probe on pin 3 of NE555DR (sorry don't have a USB key right now):

[image: Oscilloscope capture]

[EDIT]
I went and checked the OUT frequency before and after the diode, that's where the issue comes I guess:

Here is the probe before D9 [1081180](https://fr.farnell.com/nexperia/bas16-215/diode-de-commutation-100v-215ma/dp/1081180?st=1081180):

[image: Probe before D9]

Here is the probe after D9:

[image: Probe after D9]

[EDIT]
Continued troubleshooting here's new infos:

Desoldered D9 and powered the circuit: no changes I'm losing the 555 frequency after the diode.

Resoldered D9, desoldered Q25 and powered the circuit: no changes, same as before.

When I power the power supply at 9V and allow a little bit of current it instantly goes to something like 5V (instead of 9V) so I guess that's another proof that something is wrong somewhere.

Comment: Probe between 555 pins 1 (GND) and 3 (Out) for <1s; if pulses are visible on the screen then the 555 is working.  Could the MOSFET pin-out be different than the footprint?

Comment: NE555 farnell code is 3121192

Comment: I have 29kHz on pin 3 30mV

Comment: Q26 getting a little hot (potentially even enough to feel very hot to the touch, since that would only be about 50~60 °C or so) is no surprise; if it's getting extremely hot (enough to boil water) you may have a problem.

Comment: I mean I'm limiting current to 1 amp i guess if I put 3/4A it's going to go in flames ?

Comment: Check your LM117 circuit. The LM117 is a Three-Pin Adjustable Regulator with Vin, Vout, and Adj pins (not ground) like the LM317 you have below. It needs similar connections like the LM317 but calculated for 5V instead of 9V. You probably are looking for the LM7805 fixed 5V regulator with Vin, Vout, and Ground pins instead of the LM117?

Comment: Check the footprint for Q25. Base and emitter are backwards. For some reason Rohm number backwards to everyone else. Flip the transistor and bend the legs a little. Job done.

Comment: @VictorTito the +5V rail is working fine the farnell code is 2383003 in case that is of any use

Comment: @Kartman Are you sure ? From the datasheet and the simulation below it seems ok ? Q25 ?

Comment: @Mat, I have checked the Farnel code, and it points to a TI Part No: LM1117SX-5.0/NOPBLM1117SX-5.0/NOPB. Checking the TI datasheet for that part number I can see that "it is available in five fixed voltages, 1.8 V, 2.5 V, 3.3 V, and 5 V." Didn't know that. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

30mV pulses on the 555 pin 3 indicate that either Q25 or Q26 are mis-wired, shorted, or wrong type; and/or R41 is a very low value. But something after the 555 pin 3 is misbehaving; should be seeing 9V pulses.

This does run in simulation:

[image: 555 Boost Driver]

Note that I drew this with power input on the left and output on the right.  This is the "conventional" way of drawing schematics, flowing from left to right.

Also note there is some significant ringing on the MOSFET gate around 0v in this simulation (not shown here.)  Simulations are only so-good; suggest measuring this after the main issue is found to see what really happens there.  And I had to change D8 to a (random) different type; the closest [LTspice](https://www.analog.com/en/design-center/design-tools-and-calculators/ltspice-simulator.html) has is the ES3B and that was limiting output to ~100V.

If you feel like giving this a try with LTspice, here is the .asc file:

```
Version 4
SHEET 1 1084 680
WIRE 384 -368 -224 -368
WIRE 704 -368 464 -368
WIRE 784 -368 704 -368
WIRE 896 -368 848 -368
WIRE 960 -368 896 -368
WIRE 1008 -368 960 -368
WIRE 704 -336 704 -368
WIRE 368 -256 -96 -256
WIRE 464 -256 368 -256
WIRE 496 -256 464 -256
WIRE 608 -256 560 -256
WIRE 656 -256 608 -256
WIRE 896 -256 896 -368
WIRE 1008 -256 1008 -368
WIRE 368 -208 368 -256
WIRE 608 -208 608 -256
WIRE -224 -192 -224 -368
WIRE -96 -192 -96 -256
WIRE 464 -160 464 -256
WIRE 544 -160 464 -160
WIRE -224 -80 -224 -112
WIRE -96 -80 -96 -112
WIRE 368 -80 368 -128
WIRE 608 -80 608 -112
WIRE 704 -80 704 -240
WIRE 896 -80 896 -192
WIRE 1008 -80 1008 -176
FLAG -96 -80 0
FLAG 704 -80 0
FLAG -224 -80 0
FLAG 368 -80 0
FLAG 608 -80 0
FLAG 896 -80 0
FLAG 1008 -80 0
FLAG 960 -368 VOUT
SYMBOL voltage -96 -208 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 24 124 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName V1
SYMATTR Value PULSE(0 9 1m 1n 1n 10u 34.483u 420)
SYMATTR SpiceLine Rser=10
SYMBOL sym\\nmos 656 -336 R0
SYMATTR InstName Q26
SYMATTR Value IRF740
SYMBOL pnp 544 -112 M180
WINDOW 0 60 64 Left 2
WINDOW 3 57 37 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName Q25
SYMATTR Value 2N2907
SYMBOL voltage -224 -208 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 24 124 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName V2
SYMATTR Value 9
SYMATTR SpiceLine Rser=1
SYMBOL ind 368 -352 R270
WINDOW 0 32 56 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 5 56 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName L1
SYMATTR Value 100µ
SYMATTR SpiceLine Ipk=1 Rser=0.16 Rpar=53868.3 Cpar=0 mfg="Bourns, Inc." pn="SRU1048-101Y"
SYMBOL diode 496 -240 R270
WINDOW 0 32 32 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 0 32 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName D9
SYMATTR Value 1N914
SYMBOL res 352 -224 R0
SYMATTR InstName R41
SYMATTR Value 1k
SYMBOL schottky 784 -352 R270
WINDOW 0 32 32 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 0 32 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName D8
SYMATTR Value UPSC600
SYMATTR Description Diode
SYMATTR Type diode
SYMBOL cap 880 -256 R0
SYMATTR InstName C9
SYMATTR Value 1µ
SYMATTR SpiceLine V=400 Irms=0 Rser=0.0252581 Lser=10.4595n mfg="Würth Elektronik" pn="890283326009CS WCAP-FTBP 22.5 x 26 x 17 x 8.5" type="Box"
SYMBOL res 992 -272 R0
SYMATTR InstName RL
SYMATTR Value 100k
TEXT -32 -152 Left 2 ;Simulated 555 output
TEXT -42 -304 Left 2 !.tran 15m startup uic
```

Comment: Thanks for the simulation I guess I should start to learn this software.
The voltage never stabilize or it's because you stop the soft or didn't implement the Q24 circuit ?

Comment: Right, this is just a bare-bones test to see how the gate pulsing section works.  It could be expanded with the entire circuit, but this will slow it way down and the results may not represent actuality very well.

Comment: I downoladed LTSpice 17 and wanted to try your circuit, the IRF740 is missing from the available nmos.
I tried adding it in standard.mos but with no luck could you share your config ?
.model IRF740 VDMOS(Kp=3.1089 Rs=0.0048 Rd=0.4166 Rg=0.91 Vto=4.5 Lambda=0.001 Cgdmax=1218p Cgdmin=15p Cgs=1300p tt=533n Is=2.41E-09 N=1.401 Rb=0.013053 M=0.452 Vj=0.36 Cjo=1424.39pF mfg=STmicro Qg=35n Ron=0.48 Vds=400)

Comment: Hmm, that's identical to what I have so it should be working.  Try right-clicking Q26 and pick a different MOSFET.

Comment: Picking another one works like the 2N7002, the results are not what I expect but it works
I can't see the IRF740 in the list very strange
Can you share your standard.mos file if that's possible so I can try it out ?

Comment: @rdtsc Didn't know where to reply, but you shouldn't have deleted [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/606630/95619). It's true you can't have `.param` statements with `time`, but you can have `.func` or, for that OP's case, a behavioural source with whatever desired expression, using `V(1)` and `V(2)`. Just modify the answer and undelete it -- a subcircuit *is* a black box, it's just a matter of implementation. (give a short reply there, so I'll know to delete this comment)